# Where are allure is located?

Tags: software-installation

I have installed allure on the ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install allure
```

install allure command end with:

> ...
> Unpacking allure (0.5.0.0-1) ...
> Setting up libgtk2.0-common (2.24.32-1ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.32-1ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up libgail18:amd64 (2.24.32-1ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up libgail-common:amd64 (2.24.32-1ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up allure (0.5.0.0-1) ...
> Setting up libgtk2.0-bin (2.24.32-1ubuntu1) ...
> Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...

So, it seems allure installed successfully

Now I try to verify allure:

`allure --version`:

> allure: command not found

Also I do not found allure in `/usr/bin/allure` - not exist

Also I try to search 'allure/bin' folder in the system:

`find / -name allure/bin -type d 2>/dev/null`

> empty result.

So.

How to found allure?

Comment: Look at `/usr/games/Allure`

Answer (score 3):

The command `dpkg-query -L allure`, should list all files that are part of that package.

The executable is called `Allure` (notice the upper case A).